# Clarify how education & experience levels are defined and used in the 2018 salary calculator

Tags: discussion, salary-calculator

First, apologies if this shouldn't be its own post - I didn't see anything posted yet for the "new" 2018 calculator, nor addressing these specific issues in the previous versions.

The newly updated [Salary Calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary) is interesting, but I'm wondering if the "education" and "years of experience" components could/ought to be more specific.

**Do the salary models assume *relevant* degrees?** 
Or is it enough that you have **a** degree to prove you are organized and mature enough to complete work at that particular level?

I have a BS and MA, but neither is related to programming. I've taken some relevant undergrad math/CS/engineering classes and am currently working as a full-stack mobile app & web developer, but I don't yet have a CS degree. So what do I choose?

It would be helpful to clarify the model's assumptions on this point, so users could answer appropriately and get more accurate salary estimates.

**Does "years of experience" refer to my current position & skills?**

Or does it refer, as one might expect, to career experience in the field overall?

I have anywhere from 0.5 to 15 years of experience depending which subset of my career history and skill sets I choose to focus on, and how I decide to define my 'experience'. Is the model assuming I have  the same 'X'yrs of experience across the board in all of the languages and skills I list? That wouldn't be accurate either.

Knowing more specifically how "experience" is defined by & used in the salary models would also help people determine how to answer & get more accurate estimates.

Finally: just a note that the salary expectations (for a range of education & experience choices) seem rather inflated compared to stats for my current city on Glassdoor, Indeed and [U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics (2017 data)](https://www.bls.gov/oes/current/oessrcst.htm). I'm on the low end of "median" for my area (hooray underpaid state govt!) according to all of the above, but this calculator shows me not even breaking into the bottom quartile. Is this a function of job posting salary ranges low-balling applicants? Or is the salary data itself not quite accurate?

Answer (score 2):

I am quite sympathetic to these concerns, as I've been paid to code in some form since the late 1990s but have had the title "data scientist" for <5 years. How many "years of professional experience" should I claim? These definitions are cut and dried for very few developers.

The data used for the modeling in the Salary Calculator is from the 2018 Developer Survey. You can check out the responses for [years of professional coding experience](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018#developer-profile-years-coding-professionally) and [formal education](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018#developer-profile-educational-attainment) for yourself to understand how our respondents understood these questions. Especially notice what the underlying distributions are and how your own characteristics might result in some variation there.

Comment: Ok, so since ~90% of respondents with a degree got it in CS, engr, math, etc, "Do you have a degree?" likely assumes a "relevant" degree. Mine are in Asian Studies, so I'm an edge case ... But then so are many of the non-traditional, 2nd-degree, and Bootcamp students/graduates who "learned to code" in the last 5yrs as a career shift ... I've coded for work at times since 2002, but didn't have any formal education in it until 2010, or the job title until 2016. Who knows - maybe that'll help me appear younger and more appealing to employers who otherwise only hire single 22y.o.s!